Non-informative prior in Bayesian Linear Regression
It's known that in Bayesian Linear Regression with $\text{Inv-}\Gamma(a_0, b_0)$ prior on variance parameter $\sigma^2$, the posterior distribution after $n$ observations $(X, Y)$ is $f(\beta, \sigma^2\mid X, Y)=f(\beta\mid X, Y, \sigma^2)\cdot f(\sigma^2\mid X, Y)$. The second term is $\text{Inv-}\Gamma(a_1, b_1)$ distribution with $a_1=a_0+\frac n 2$.
I am trying to reconcile it with two other facts. The first fact is that in the standard linear regression (frequentist approach) the estimator $\hat\beta=(X^TX)^{-1}X^TY$ follows $k$-dimensional multivariate $t$-distribution centered at model parameter $\beta_0$ with $n-k$ degrees of freedom:
$t(k, \beta_0, (\hat{\sigma^2})(X^TX)^{-1}, n-k)$.The second fact is that non-informative prior for Bayesian linear regression must have $a_0=b_0=0$ so that improper prior on $\sigma^2$ is $f(\sigma^2)\propto \frac 1 \sigma^2$.
However, taking the posterior $f(\beta, \sigma^2\mid X, Y)$ with $a_0=b_0=0$ and integrating out $\sigma^2$ to get marginal distribution distribution $\beta$ gives $t$-distribution with $n$-degrees of freedom.
$$\int_{\sigma^2} \frac{1}{\left(2\pi\sigma^2\right)^{k/2}\det\Sigma_1}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(\beta-\mu_1)^T\Sigma^{-1}_{1}(\beta - \mu_1)\right)\cdot \frac{b_1^{a_1}}{\Gamma(a_1)}\frac{1}{(\sigma^2)^{n/2+1}}\exp\left(-\frac {b_1}{\sigma^2}\right)d\sigma^2$$
Where above $\mu_1$ and $\Sigma_1$ are parameters for posterior $f(\beta\mid X, Y, \sigma^2)$ which is known to be Gaussian. The power of sigma in the integrand is $k/2+n/2+1$ and it will give rise to a distribution $f(\beta\mid X, Y)\propto (1+\beta^T V \beta)^{-(n+k)/2}$. So I am picking up $n$ degrees of freedom instead of $n-k$. Something must be off here. Could you point out the flaw in the logic?

The likelihood function does not have $\sigma^{-k}$ in it, so where are you getting that term from?  Also, you should show the steps of your derivation from the likelihood to the joint posterior.  Otherwise, there's no way to point out a flaw in the derivation other than to guess.
